# Can't open and install any snaps including snap-store

Tags: 20.04, snap, snap-store

So I have a problem.
The thing is that every time I open a snap this happens:

(For snap-store:)

```
jakob@SnurfsPC:~$ snap-store
/snap/snap-store/518/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 50: /home/jakob/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
sed: can't read /home/jakob/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
/snap/snap-store/518/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 251: /home/jakob/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
cp: cannot open '/home/jakob/.config/user-dirs.locale' for reading: Permission denied
/snap/snap-store/518/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 256: /home/jakob/.config/user-dirs.locale: Permission denied
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/snap/snap-store/518/gnome-platform/usr/share/mime': No such file or directory
Directory '/home/jakob/snap/snap-store/518/.local/share/mime/packages' does not exist!
/snap/snap-store/518/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 20: /snap/snap-store/518/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0: No such file or directory
ERROR: /snap/snap-store/518/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0 exited abnormally with status 127
ERROR: update-mime-database /home/jakob/snap/snap-store/518/.local/share/mime exited abnormally with status 1
/snap/snap-store/518/usr/bin/snap-store: error while loading shared libraries: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

(for other snaps, here yuzu:)

```
jakob@SnurfsPC:~$ yuzu
/snap/yuzu/296/bin/desktop-launch: line 51: /home/jakob/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
/home/jakob/snap/yuzu/common/.cache/gio-modules/libdconfsettings.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/jakob/snap/yuzu/common/.cache/gio-modules/libdconfsettings.so
/home/jakob/snap/yuzu/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognutls.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/jakob/snap/yuzu/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognutls.so
/home/jakob/snap/yuzu/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/jakob/snap/yuzu/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so
/home/jakob/snap/yuzu/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognomeproxy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/jakob/snap/yuzu/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognomeproxy.so
Error: unable to open display :0
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Abgebrochen (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

I first thought the problem was gtk or qt, but i installed everything i could find about them.
I have no Idea how to fix this.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you recently performed a `chown -R` or `chmod -R` in your home directory? 

Comment: No, what does it do?

Comment: There are “permission denied” errors, so I was checking to see if the permissions in your home directory had been changed 

Comment: The permissions of my homedir are: 
`Owner: read, write, execute ;
Group: read ,execute ;
Other: read, execute` is this normal?

Comment: Who is the owner?

Comment: I am the owner.

Comment: In Kubuntu 22.04 Firefox doesn't start with similar issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412576/firefox-doesnt-start-in-kubuntu-22-04