# Firefox doesn't start in Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, 22.04

Fresh install of Kubuntu 22.04. Clicking on the Firefox icon doesn't work. In the command line some error messages can be seen:

```
$ firefox
sed: can't read /home/mama/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
/snap/firefox/1232/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 261: /home/mama/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
cp: cannot open '/home/mama/.config/user-dirs.locale' for reading: Permission denied
/snap/firefox/1232/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 266: /home/mama/.config/user-dirs.locale: Permission denied
/snap/firefox/1232/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 20: /snap/firefox/1232/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0: No such file or directory
ERROR: /snap/firefox/1232/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0 exited abnormally with status 127
/snap/firefox/1232/firefox.launcher: 47: xdg-user-dir: not found
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /snap/firefox/1232/usr/lib/firefox/libmozgtk.so:
libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: You can try to start Firefox again after [switching from Wayland to Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406844/ubuntu-22-04-fresh-installation-firefox-will-no-load/1406857#1406857). (If you run Xorg already, we have to look for another cause of the problem.)

Comment: @sudodus, mentioned article recommends to edit file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, but I don't have it. Kubuntu uses SDDM instead of GDM. How to ensure Xorg session in Kubuntu?

Comment: I forgot about the difference between the flavours. Maybe it is not even running Wayland. Check with the command `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`

Comment: @sudodus `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` prints `x11`.

Comment: We have to look for some other cause of the problem. I see from the output to the terminal, that you have Firefox via snap. Were there any errors during the installation? Please check if Firefox works, when you boot live from the USB installation drive. - Unfortunately its getting late here. I'll be back tomorrow, but if you are lucky, someone else will be able to help you before I'm back.

Comment: @sudodus Yes, Ubuntu 22.04 & all flavors have the Firefox as snap. There is no more normal apt package. apt package exists, but it is actually a stub which proceeds with installation of the snap. It's fresh OS installation, Firefox comes OOB. I just expected it will work. I assume if OS installation didn't fail, Firefox snap installation should have been successful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136852/discussion-between-sudodus-and-ivan-ukr).

Comment: Issue with similar error message (`.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied`) but in 20.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335708/cant-open-and-install-any-snaps-including-snap-store - but still no answer there.

Comment: Another similar one https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591130/snap-store-or-basically-any-snap-app-cannot-be-run-user-dirs-dirs-permission-d

Answer (score 1):

Following question [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22) suggests one of possible solutions: remove Firefox snap and install it from Mozilla Team PPA. Another working solution is to again remove snap and install via flatpak (Flathub link: https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.mozilla.firefox). Hoping some day snap will be fixed and will be usable. At the moment it is not.